# adding javascript widget code the right way

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, widget

I give customers javscript code that adds a widget to their website.
Currently I ask them to paste this right above the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + myHost + "www.mywebsite.com/mycode.js.php?u="+encodeURIComponent(window.location.host)+"' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

As you can see the code calls my script under http or https url depending on the page url.

Sometimes when a website html is not well formed the script can cause ["operation aborted"](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx) bug on IE browsers.

I want to send customers code that will be attached to the `<head>` area.

1. How can I handle the http/https when calling code from head part?
2. Do you know if it will solve the operation aborted problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give them the HTTPS solution.

If their page is secure, it'll work fine; If not, there's nothing wrong with embedding a secure object in an insecure page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/mycode.js.php"></script>
```

I can see you're passing the original domain in the querystring. You can fetch that from your JS code without the need for passing it through a GET parameter. You can check it using the `document.referrer` property.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google handles their analytics code the exact same way (which I'm sure you know).  What are you doing in your code?  When I looked at the "operation aborted" link you provided it says as a solution to execute your code when the page has been loaded.

I'd recommend binding a function to the onload event and executing your DOM-manipulating code there.

Comment: Thanks!.
I have a function that binds to the onload event.